# Jersey 2: how can I set values in an injectable class, so they are available when that class is injected into an API resource?

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey-2.0, hk2

I have moved from Jersey 1.19 to: Jersey 2.41 with HK2 and Jetty 10.0.20. Java version is 17.

Note: this is not my area of expertise - I managed to get the REST server working for v1 and I need to do the same for v2.

In my v1 code, in the class that starts the HTTPServer, I set values in the class to be injected (ISyslogServerParm), as follows:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new SyslogAPIModule());
ISyslogServerParms serverParms = injector.getInstance(ISyslogServerParms.class);
serverParms.setEventTrackers(eventTrackers);
```

I have spent all day trying to find out how to do this with Jersey 2, without success.
I have got to the point of using the *ResourceConfig*, but I'm basically lost.

ISyslogServerParms gets injected OK. What I can't find a way to do, is to invoke *setEventtrackers()*... somewhere.

*The API*:

```
package com.w3p.api;
@Path("njams")
public class MyMessageAPI { 
    @Inject
    private ISyslogServerParms syslogServerParms;

    @POST
    @Path("syslog")
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public Response handleSysLogMsg(String syslogData) {
    ...
    }
```

*The REST serve*r:

```
    public class MyRestServer {

    private final List<String> eventTrackers; 
    
    public MyRestServer(List<String> eventTrackers) {           
        this.eventTrackers = eventTrackers;
    }

    public void run() {
        ApplicationConfig config = new ApplicationConfig(eventTrackers);
        ...
    }
}
```

The *ResourceConfig*

```
public class ApplicationConfig extends ResourceConfig{  
    @Inject
    public ApplicationConfig(List<String> eventTrackers) {List<String> eventTrackers) {
       packages("com.w3p.api");       
       register(new ApplicationBinder());
       ServiceLocator locator = ServiceLocatorFactory.getInstance().create("MyMessageAPI");
       ISyslogServerParms parms = locator.getService(ISyslogServerParms.class); 
       parms.setEventTrackers(eventTrackers);
    }
```

The above use of a ServiceLocator is guesswork based on replies and documentation. I didn't expect *parms* to be magically resolved, and it is indeed null.

I would be really grateful if someone could provide me with guidance on how I should go about solving this.

Comment: This looks like you are using guice, not hk2

Comment: Hi @jwells131313 Many thanks for replyiing. I wa susing Guice with Jersey 1.19. But with 2.41, HK2 is in my pom.xml and guice has been removed.